# Ajax chat creating a new file on every chat

Tags: php, ajax, chat

I'm trying to achieve a working chat that creates a new log file on every chat. 
This is the code:

```
<?
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['logout'])){ 

    //Simple exit message
    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'><i>User ". $_SESSION['name'] ." has left the chat session.</i><br></div>");
    fclose($fp);

    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); //Redirect the user
}

function loginForm(){
    echo'
    <div id="loginform">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>Anna nimimerkki:</p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
    </form>
    </div>
    ';
}

if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
    else{
        echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat - Customer Module</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    loginForm();
}
else{
?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>  
    <div id="chatbox"><?php
    if(file_exists("log.html") && filesize("log.html") > 0){
        $handle = fopen("log.html", "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize("log.html"));
        fclose($handle);

        echo $contents;
    }
    ?></div>

    <form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    //If user submits the form
    $("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
        return false;
    });

    //Load the file containing the chat log
    function loadLog(){     
        var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
        $.ajax({
            url: "log.html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){        
                $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
                var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
                if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                }               
            },
        });
    }
    setInterval (loadLog, 2500);    //Reload file every 2.5 seconds

    //If user wants to end session
    $("#exit").click(function(){
        var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
        if(exit==true){window.location = 'index.php?logout=true';}      
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok, heres what it does: It checks for the log.html file, if it exists, it shows it and all the messages in it. All the messages sent from the chat will be saved to log.html and so on the log.html would be HUGE when there would be a lot of messages. BUT. If the log.html file doesn't exist, it will create it, so I need to create a new log.html on every session start. 
I tried using a random string generator:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = ’0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ’;
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

// Echo the random string.
// Optionally, you can give it a desired string length.
echo generateRandomString();
```

The generator works fine, and so on. I realized that I need to assign the randomstring as a variable to be able to the SAME random string multiple times on the page. So I did this:

```
$LOGFILE = generateRandomString();
```

This uses the same random string (for example: abcdefg ) every time I echo it right? 
The problem comes with the javascript part. I've tried this:

```
...
function loadLog(){     
        var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
        $.ajax({
            url: <?php echo $LOGFILE ;?>".html",
...
```

But it wont echo anything to it when I check the code.

I've modified the code so it will use the random string on any part when it needs to access the log file, like this:

```
<?
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['logout'])){    

    //Simple exit message
    $fp = fopen($LOGFILE,".html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'><i>User ". $_SESSION['name'] ." has left the chat session.</i><br></div>");
    fclose($fp);

    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); //Redirect the user
...
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing that is definitely wrong at first glance is `url: <?php echo $LOGFILE ;?>".html",` - should be `url: "<?php echo $LOGFILE ;?>.html",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the error I got mentioned about, but it still not working. When I look at the source code with Chrome I noticed this:

```
//Load the file containing the chat log
    function loadLog(){     
        var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
        $.ajax({
        !!!!!   url: ".html",!!!!!!!
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){        
                $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
                var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
                if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                }               
            },
        });
    }
```

So it's not echoing the php variable. Here's the whole code:

```
<?
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['logout'])){ 

    //Simple exit message
    $fp = fopen($LOGFILE,".html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'><i>User ". $_SESSION['name'] ." has left the chat session.</i><br></div>");
    fclose($fp);

    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); //Redirect the user
}
function generateRandomString($length = 5) {
    $characters = '12345logLOG';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$LOGFILE = $randomString ;

function loginForm(){
    echo'
    <div id="loginform">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>Anna nimimerkki:</p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
    </form>
    </div>
    ';
}

if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
    else{
        echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat - Customer Module</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    loginForm();
}
else{
?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>  
    <div id="chatbox"><?php
    if(file_exists($LOGFILE,".html") && filesize($LOGFILE,".html") > 0){
        $handle = fopen($LOGFILE,".html", "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($LOGFILE,".html"));
        fclose($handle);

        echo $contents;
    }
    ?></div>

    <form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    //If user submits the form
    $("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
        return false;
    });

    //Load the file containing the chat log
    function loadLog(){     
        var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $LOGFILE ;?>.html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){        
                $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
                var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
                if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                }               
            },
        });
    }
    setInterval (loadLog, 2500);    //Reload file every 2.5 seconds

    //If user wants to end session
    $("#exit").click(function(){
        var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
        if(exit==true){window.location = 'index.php?logout=true';}      
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
enter code here
```